# Why is this composite index empty?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a Datastore (Firestore in Datastore mode) database/entity with the following composite index:

```
- kind: spider-results
  properties:
  - name: created
    direction: desc
  - name: meta
  - name: score
```

This has been applied two days ago, but my index doesn't contain any entities.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

The entities have more attributes than the three contained in the index. In Python using `google-cloud-datastore` version 1.7.1 I was trying to fetch entities. To make queries as fast as possible and return only the fields contained in the index, I set the `projection` argument:

```
client = datastore.Client.from_service_account_json(credentials_path)
query = client.query(kind='spider-results', order=['-created'],
                     projection=['created', 'meta', 'score'])
for entity in query.fetch(eventual=True):
    print(entity.key.name)
```

However, this yields no result. My understanding is that this is caused by the matching index being empty.

When I remove the `projection` argument, the query yields results (containing some relatively large fields which cause significant data transfer, slowing down the entire query.

Comment: Was the index by any chance created _after_ the entities were already written? Are all 3 of the properties indexed? Check also the `Limitations on projections` section at the end of [Restrictions on queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#restrictions_on_queries).

Comment: The composite index size of 0 is likely the culprit, it means no results will show up in the queries using it. I suspect that when you drop the projection the query remains simple enough to not actually use the composite index.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Yes, the index has been created after the entities were created. My Python code uses `Entity.update()` to write entities. I am now running the process and curious whether this will fill the index. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I got confused, re-writing the entities is needed only when changing properties from non-indexed to indexed. The initial index upload goes through the index building stage, which I presume scans all existing entities and adding them to the index without them being explicitly re-written.